# ASP.NET user control in jQuery UI dialog on button click

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, user-controls

Using ASP.NET 3.5 and jQuery UI.

When a user clicks the "Search" button, a User Control, containing a search form, should be displayed in a jQuery UI Dialog (popup).

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply put the ASP.NET user control inside the `<div>` which is the jQuery popup.  I've done this countless times and it works fine.

Comment: How do I make the div popup when the button is pressed?

Comment: set it's style:display='none' in the HTML and I've been using the simplemodal plugin to show the popups:  http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the ASP.NET user control inside the  which is the jQuery popup successfully?